# Do environment variables sync with a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables

I've created a virtual environment (.venv) for my Python 3 project
I'm running this on a Windows 10 machine and saving the Database credentials, e.g. db_pwd, inside an environment variable so it doesnt get exposed on Github.

When I update the variable using the machine powershell, e.g. opening from Windows start > Powershell app, the PS from (.venv) doesn't update the environment variable.

Is this a feature? I thought .venv was there just to help avoid all those pip -install libraries from being shipped with the project.

NB: I'm a newbie on this, please be kind :)

Comment: The .venv is read info the the project uses.  It doesn't create new info that is available to other processes.  See : https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: The link you sent was useful to deepen my knowledge on venv. I understand better how isolation works, but I'm trying to update the OS variable, which IMO is external to the venv, shouldn't that persist?

Comment: Are you saying you update the environment variable while you have a running Powershell session?  I'm pretty sure that won't work; the shell only sees the environment that existed when it started.  Does it work if you restart the shell?

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn, that solved the issue. Just restarting the venv solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The virtual environment needs to be restarted
As per BrenBarn comments, the python virtual environment (venv) holds an old copy of the OS environment variable